# How to rotate packed quadwords in xmm register?

Tags: x86, sse2

Given an 128-bit `xmm` register that is packed with two quadwords (i.e. two 64-bit integers):

```
     ╭──────────────────┬──────────────────╮
xmm0 │ ffeeddccbbaa9988 │ 7766554433221100 │
     ╰──────────────────┴──────────────────╯
```

How can i perform a *rotate* on the individual quadwords? For example:

```
prorqw xmm0, 32   // rotate right packed quadwords

     ╭──────────────────┬──────────────────╮
xmm0 │ bbaa9988ffeeddcc │ 3322110077665544 │
     ╰──────────────────┴──────────────────╯
```

I know SSE2 provides:

- **`PSHUFW`**: *shuffle packed **words*** (16-bits)
- **`PSHUFD`**: *shuffle packed **doublewords*** (32-bits)

Although i don't know what the instructions do, nor is there a **quadword** (64-bit) version.

## Bonus Question

How would you perform a `ROR` of an `xmm` register - assuming packed data of *other* sizes?

- Rotate Right Packed **doublewords** by 16-bits:

  ```
       ╭──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────╮
  xmm0 │ ffeeddcc │ bbaa9988 │ 77665544 │ 33221100 │
       ╰──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────╯
                          ⇓
       ╭──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────╮
  xmm0 │ ddccffee │ 9988bbaa │ 55447766 │ 11003322 │
       ╰──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────╯
  ```
- Rotate Right Packed **Words** by 8-bits:

  ```
       ╭──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────╮
  xmm0 │ ffee │ ddcc │ bbaa │ 9988 │ 7766 │ 5544 │ 3322 │ 1100 │
       ╰──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────╯
                          ⇓
       ╭──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────╮
  xmm0 │ eeff │ ccdd │ aabb │ 8899 │ 6677 │ 4455 │ 2233 │ 0011 │
       ╰──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────╯
  ```

### Extra bonus question

How would you perform the above if it was a 256-bit `ymm` register?

```
     ╭──────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────╮
ymm0 │ 2f2e2d2c2b2a29282726252423222120 │ ffeeddccbbaa99887766554433221100 │ packed doublequadwords
     ╰──────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────╯
     ╭──────────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────╮
ymm0 │ 2f2e2d2c2b2a2928 │ 2726252423222120 │ ffeeddccbbaa9988 │ 7766554433221100 │ packed quadwords
     ╰──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────╯
     ╭──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────╮
ymm0 │ 2f2e2d2c │ 2b2a2928 │ 27262524 │ 23222120 │ ffeeddcc │ bbaa9988 │ 77665544 │ 33221100 │ packed doublewords
     ╰──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────╯
     ╭──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────╮
ymm0 │ 2f2e │ 2d2c │ 2b2a │ 2928 │ 2726 │ 2524 │ 2322 │ 2120 │ ffee │ ddcc │ bbaa │ 9988 │ 7766 │ 5544 │ 3322 │ 1100 │ packed words
     ╰──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────╯
```

## Bonus Reading

- [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=88,79,5619,5163&text=pshuf)
- [X86 Opcode and Instruction Reference Home](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html)
- [Rotation or Shifting with x86/x64 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117537/rotation-or-shifting-with-x86-x64-assembly)
- [PSHUFW explanation?](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/430880-mmx-asm-pshufw-explanation/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rotate count is a multiple of 8, you can use byte shuffles.  [SSSE3 `pshufb`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFB.html) with a control mask can handle any other multiple of 8 in one instruction.

[SSE2 `pshufd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFD.html) can handle count=32, swapping the two halves of each qword: `_MM_SHUFFLE(2,3, 0,1)`, or in asm `pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0b10_11_00_01` (NASM supports `_` as an optional separator, like C++11 for numeric literals.)

[SSE2 `pshuflw` + `pshufhw`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFLW.html) for multiple-of-16 counts is not bad for a version of your function without SSSE3, but you need separate shuffles for the low/high qword.  (An imm8 control byte only holds four 2-bit fields.)  Or with AVX2, for the odd/even qwords within each lane.

---

**If the rotate count is *not* a multiple of 8**, there's AVX512F [`vprolq zmm0, zmm1, 13`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPROLD:VPROLVD:VPROLQ:VPROLVQ.html) and `vprorq`.  Also available in variable-count version, with per-element counts from another vector instead of an immediate.  `vprolvq` / `vprorvq`.  Also available in dword granularity, but not word or byte.

---

**Otherwise with only SSE2 and a count that's not a multiple of 16 you need left+right shift + OR** to actually implement in asm the common way of expressing a rotate in C as **`(x << n) | (x >> (64-n))`**.  ([Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c/13732181) points out ways to work around the potential C UB from out of range shift counts, which isn't a problem with intrinsics or asm because the behaviour of asm and intrinsics is well-defined by Intel: SIMD shifts saturate the shift count, instead of masking it like scalar shifts.)

SSE2 has shifts with granularity as small as 16-bit, so you can do that directly.

For byte granularity, you'd need extra masking to zero out bits that shifted between bytes in a word.  [Efficient way of rotating a byte inside an AVX register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983192/efficient-way-of-rotating-a-byte-inside-an-avx-register).  Or use tricks like `pmullw` with a vector of power-of-2 elements, allowing variable counts per element.  (Where AVX2 normally only has variable-count shifts for dword/qword).

Comment: How do you use `pshufd` to rotate the two quadwords in `xmm0` by 32 bits?

Comment: @IanBoyd: you swap the 32-bit halves of each qword.  Like `_MM_SHUFFLE(2,3,  0,1)` with intrinsics.  Or in asm directly, `pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0b10_11_00_01`  (you probably have to remove the `_` separators I used between pairs of bits, unless your assemble supports a C++11 style separator syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Although i asked about performing **rotate right**, one subset of ROR is when you perform ROR of two 64-bits value by exactly 32 bits. This makes your arbitrary *rotate* turn into a simple swap of the high and the low 32-bits:

[image]

Knowing that you're simply performing a 32-bit (i.e. **doubleword**) swap, you can use another instruction:

- **pshufd**: Shuffle Packed Doublewords

The encoding of the instruction is tricky, and Intel does its best to [obfuscate the documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=88,79,5619,5163,5110&text=PSHUFD). The idea is that you can treat the 128-bit xmm as 32-bit **doublewords**, and push them to wherever you like:

[image]

The encoding is tricky:

```
pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0x02030001
```

Because i'm pushing ***four*** doublewords around, the mask is made up of four chunks:

> `02` `03` `00` `01`

These are arranged left-to-right, telling you the index of where that 32-bit doubleword should be shuffled to:

[image]

If you are rotating 64-bit quadwords, that are packed into an `xmm` register, by exactly 32-bits, you can use:

```
pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0x02030001 //rotate packed quadwords by 32-bits¹
```

## RotateRight(16)

Now what if:

- rather than `ROR(32)` of the 64-bit quadwords packed into xmm
- i wanted to `ROR(16)`

[image]

We can apply the same trick. Assume that the 64-bit quadwords are divided into 16-bit words, and shuffle them:

[image]

```
pshufw xmm0, xmm0, 0x0605040702010003 //shuffle packed words¹
```

Except pshufw cannot operate on xmm registers. So i've talked myself to a standstill.

## RotateRight(24)

Now what if:

- rather than `ROR(32)` of the 64-bit quadwords packed into xmm
- i wanted to `ROR(24)`

[image]

We can apply the same things. Assume that the 64-bit quadwords are divided into 8-bit words....

pshufb xmm0, xmm0, something  //shuffle packed bytes

Well, i'll pick this up tomorrow. For now i'm tired.  I was hoping to just type in the one line of code; instead it's been a four-hour slog of pain. I just assumed people would have all these basic operations documented by now; the CPU has been around for at least 3 years.

### RotateRight(1)

Yeah, later.

### Footnotes

¹I think. I'm not sure i got the encoding right.

Comment: The "obfuscated documentation" you linked to is Intel's *intrinsics* guide.  It's intended for people writing in C or C++ with intrinsics.  For 4x 2-bit fields, you can always use the `_MM_SHUFFLE` macro.  But if you're writing in asm directly, you should consult Intel's vol.2 instruction set ref manual, or an HTML extract like http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFD.html.   
 The OPERATION section uses different pseudocode to describe it, in terms of a shift.  But it has a diagram example for 256-bit vpshufb.  (I added links to my answer for the insns I mentioned.)

Comment: And BTW, `0x02030001` is a 32-bit constant written in hex.  You need an 8-bit constant like `0xb1` or `0b10110001`.  The 4 chunks are 2-bit fields inside an immediate byte.  Once you understand it, Intel's bit-range notation is very good and unambiguously describes *exactly* what an instruction does.  No SSE/AVX insns take a 32-bit immediate, but if they did that would be enough space to encode a 16-bit granularity shuffle that covers the whole register.  (`log2(8) * 8 = 24 bits` for 8 x 3-bit fields.  Or they'd more likely use 4-bit fields, with the high bit being optional zeroing).

Comment: @PeterCordes I'll have to come back tomorrow to fix up the images. And hopefully by then i'll have answers on how to ROR.